# Show that $m^{2}=m+2\binom{m}{2}$ for all positive integers m.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> Show that $m^{2}=m+2\binom{m}{2}$ for all positive integers $m$.
>   Note: $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $n < k$.

I checked for specific values of $m$ and this equation works, but that doesn't really answer my question. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you write out the definition of $m \choose 2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $\displaystyle \binom{m}{2}=\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$

So, $\displaystyle 2\binom{m}{2}=m(m-1)$

We know that $m(m-1)+m=m(m)=m^2$.

Boom!

Comment: Boom is correct!

Answer (score 5):

$m^2$ counts the number of pairs of integers $(a,b)$ with $1\le a\le m$
and $1\le b\le m$.

How many of these pairs have $a<b$?

How many of these pairs have $a=b$?

How many of these pairs have $a>b$?

Answer (score 0):

Just $\binom{m}{2}=\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Given, 
 $m^{2}=m+2\binom{m}{2}$

Take, RHS

$m+2\binom{m}{2}$

$= m+2\times\cfrac{m(m-1)}{2}$

$= m +  m (m-1)$

$= m + (m^2-m)$

$= 2m^2 = \text{LHS}$

Note: We have $\binom{n}{k}= \cfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\cfrac{n(n-1)(n-2).....k\space\text{factor}}{k!} $; $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $n < k$, and square of any interger is always positive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generating functions. We use the notation $[x^n]$ to mean the coefficient of $x^n$ in the generating function (series). Use the fact that
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^k}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{k+n-1}{k-1}x^n\tag{1}.
$$
for $k\geq 1$ (by repeatedly differentiating the geometric series or by the extended binomial theorem) to deduce that
$$
n+2\binom{n}{2}
=[x^n]\left(\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}+2\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3}\right)
=[x^n]\left(\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}\right)
=n^2.\tag{2}
$$